# Compile python using PyInstaller, with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, compilation, exe, pyinstaller

I'm looking for a way to run PyInstaller compiling from a Python script, not the command line as it is shown in the docs.

I've looked in the docs and on the internet, but all solutions suggest to use it via the command line, `pyinstaller foo.py`

I mean to use something like,

```py
import PyInstaller
PyInstaller.compile("x.py")
```

However, I can't find any way to do it through Python itself.
All help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for activating PyInstaller from Python.

```py
from PyInstaller import __main__ as main
main.run("a")
```

I don't know why, but it won't work unless the file has a 1 letter filename.